# Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g editing, debugging) is not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, launcher

I'm on Android Studio 2.1.2 on Windows 10. I'm a beginner and I'm trying to figure out how to turn the stock launcher into a Gradle build for more functionality.

I get this:[image: Gradle fail]

I click [Show Log](http://pastebin.com/kLa0uReK) and can't find the problem by myself.
Can anyone help?

Comment: have you installed API version 23, the APIs for Android 6? (Your log, row 2043)

Comment: will do @ManuToMatic but how?

Comment: Open the SDK-Manager and install the APIs for Android 6.

Comment: I second that. In particular, `Unable to locate SDK within the Android studio installation`

Comment: @ManuToMatic so far so good downloading, will report back

Comment: Did it work, or is it still downloading @lolreppeatlol?

Comment: @ManuToMatic it's still downloading, im downloading a bunch of other SDKs too

Comment: @ManuToMatic done!q thank you so much!

Comment: Perfect! Glad it worked. I added it as an answer, so you can accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In [your Log](http://pastebin.com/kLa0uReK) on row 2043 there is the entry `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to find target with hash string 'android-23'`

This usually means that the specified API-Version is not installed.

To fix this:

- Open the SDK-Manager
- Locate the desired API-Version (In your case it's `Android 6.0`, API23).
- Select it and install it.
- Maybe you have to synchronize the gradle files again. After that, it should work.